How to expressing a joint distribution in terms of the marginal distribution with three random variables?
On Wikipedia under joint distributions I noticed this expression way of writing the joint probability density.
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{Y|X}(y|x)*f_X(x)
$$
This makes sense to me. As well as the logic if $Y$ and $X$ were independent then the joint probability would just be the product of the marginals. I was curious if we had three random variables:
Does this expansion make sense or is there a nuance that I am missing?
$$
f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = f_{Y|X,Z}(y|x,z)*f_X(x)*f_Z(z)
$$

Possibly the following makes sense: $$f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) =   f_{Z|X,Y}(z|x,y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)$$ It is a bit different from your expression where you have the product of two marginal distributions.

And the cascading version$$f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) =   f_{Z|X,Y}(z|x,y)f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_{X}(x)$$

Ahhh that makes sense
